# Threading architecture for Gameserver

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm starting to make my 2D game/engine, but have no idea of the best thread architecture to deal with clients on the server side.

Initially, I was thinking of a Thread-per-map design, rather than a Thread-per-user. But there is another ideal method?

In my concept for the maps threading, the thread would be created only at the entrance of an player on the map, and would be destroyed soon after it empties. But with this concept, a map with too much players (e.g., player stores) could cause heavy lag.

With the user threading approach, there would be a high number of threads - and thus, a high allocation of memory.

So, theres another better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe a server-wide thread pool, maps with more users using more threads than maps with few.

Comment: Try to rework your game logic into something of a state machine, where you can just call `map.Step()` to advance it from any thread. Then you can fairly easily switch between using a thread pool, a small fixed number of threads, or even a single thread.

Comment: +1 for Cory 'rework your game logic into something of a state machine' - slightly more complex, but you need that flexibility for a complex app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is just use one thread to simulate many game instances.  There are very few cases where games benefit from multithreading due to the complexities of game programming and the difficulty in partitioning memory access in any meaningful/safe/beneficial way.  Even the servers for biggest games you've heard of are single threaded for the entirety of the game logic.  For example a Diablo style game will have 1 thread per core and have each thread responsible for hundreds of games with a teensy tiny bit of cross-thread (really cross machine) logic for spinning up games.

Answer (score 0):

You will have some benefits from mulithreading arch when your server has several CPU cores. So if your game arch is pure event driven (you never wait anything in event handler) best performance will be with threads number equal to the CPU core number.